# Dialogflow entity list on server

Tags: dialogflow-es

I think this question has been asked but there are no clear answers.

The question is simple.

Can you have an entity list on the server.

For example I have a list of Product names on my database which can be really big. I want the intent to recognise these entities based on a list on the server.

The other thing I would like to do is filter an entity list.

e.g. I have a list of stores. I want it to be filtered by location, say by distance and lat long showing only stores near you when I ask a question.

Things which are so easy to do in apps seem so difficult in Dialogflow.

Please do not provide solutions which can be done on the server through webhooks. I already know about that and have used it.

I just want a better way to use entities so that the NLP can become more powerful.

Comment: Wonder what it says for the people at Google Dialogflow to answer these questions. I do see a lot of questions answered by them.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do will be using Entities with webhook.

- You may enable slot filling for the parameters.
- In the webhook, have a set of stores based on locations and hashmap with the location as key and set of stores as value.
- when the location is provided, fetch the corresponding set of stores.
- when the store is provided, see if that store is present in the set.
- reprompt if the information is not correct by resetting the context if required. 

  **UPDATE**
  You may ask the user for the product names. Match the entity name with the names in DB. If present, use it if not, provide the user with some option from the DB that may match with what the user is saying and ask them to choose one. 
  You need to think from a conversation point of view how two people communicate with each other.

Comment: This won't be really entity matching as it won't use the natural language capability of dialogflow. The store would just be part of a sentence which would have other entities too.

What I want is to be able to dynamically provide entities. 
One of the options would be to do it with the API but that seems cumbersome and may be slow.

What you are saying is like for a mobile app, not for an NLP engine.

I wish DialogFlow had allowed you to setup entities in a database and also allowed filtering of those entities by query.

Comment: see my update. you may need to design your conversation in a more natural way.

Comment: I am thinking in a natural conversation way, that's why the Dialogflow  issues. 
What you are talking about is a normal app not NLP.
Thank you for your help but I believe you haven't grasped the complexity of the problem. 
In a natural conversation the product will be part of the conversation, there will also be a brand and a company. Dialogflow has entities for this reason.
Again, my question is very simple, can the entity list be on the server and can it be filtered by criteria. 
What you are talking about is a very simplistic design which unfortunately will not work for me.

Comment: I understand your question very well and proposing an alternative solution. When two people talk it is not necessary that the other person (bot in your case) should know about every entity (product name). In that case, the other person (bot) asks supporting questions to identify the entity (product name) from his knowledge (DB service for your data) and asks the first person to confirm on the options (or similar). So what I am saying is to maintain an Entity in the Dialogflow with general product names so as to capture parameter. In the webhook verify if the product captured is correct or not.

Comment: continued....   Present the relevant product names (not all) to the user in case parameter is not captured correctly. If you are not able to capture the parameter in 2-3 supporting follow-up questions then simply deny the user in a polite fashion. Use the analytics to manually add the product name in the entity list of Dialogflow what the user was trying to provide for future cases. I hope I am able to explain my alternate way to you.

Comment: I already know the way you are talking about and have implemented it but then the app is not as convenient as it should be. This has to be done because there is a shortfall in dialogflow. The whole point of entities is to make the NLP stronger.